# Assigning an array of objects to a DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

When the dataProvider for an DataGrid is an array of objects, how do I set each column's dataField to a property of the object.

I have an ArrayCollection (say a) where each item is an object
For example `a[i] = data:Object`
Where the object data has some subproperties - `data.name`, `data.title`, `data.content` etc.

I have a DataGrid in which I want to display this data.

So I put:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="entries" dataProvider="{resultRSS}">
  <mx:columns>
<mx:Array>
  <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="data.title"/>
  <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Date" dataField="data.created"/>
</mx:Array> 
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

This doesn't seem to work at all. I get an empty DataGrid. How should I assign the dataField property, so that it shows up properly? I've tried `{data.title}` too.

Thanks.

Edit: sample of my data

```
-[]arraycollection
--[0]
----id="id1"
----data.
------title="something"
------name="something"
------text="some html"
--[1]
----id="id2"
----data.
------title="something2"
------name="something2"
------text="some html2"
```

and table should be

```
 |title     |name      |text     |
 =================================
 |something |something |some html|
 |something2|something2|somehtml2|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" initialize="initialize()">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.HierarchicalData;

        var a:Array = new Array();
        var o:Object = {};
        private function initialize():void{
          o["text"]="hello";
                  o["desc"]="Rahul";
          a.push(o);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>


    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%" sortExpertMode="true" id="adg1" designViewDataType="tree" dataProvider="{new HierarchicalData(a)}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="text" dataField="text"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="desc" dataField="desc"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

edit - ok now discard my previous answer according to your data try this

```
var a:Array = new Array();
        var o:Object = {};      
        private function stringArrayToObjectArray():void{
            o["id"]="mauj";
            var oj:Object=new Object();
            oj["title"]="aaa";
            o["data"]=oj;

            var oj1:Object=new Object();
            oj1["id"]="mauj2";
            var oj2:Object=new Object();
            oj2["title"]="qqqq";
            oj1["data"]=oj2;


            a.push(o);      
            a.push(oj1);        
        }

         private function some_labelFunc(item:Object,th:Object):String {
                return item.data.title;
            }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>



    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid  width="100%" height="100%" sortExpertMode="true" id="adg1" dataProvider="{a}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="COMPANIES" dataField="data" labelFunction="some_labelFunc"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

try this sorry for such a bad code

Comment: But the thing is I don't want to display it as a tree. I want to display it as a normal table. Only thing is, the data for the dataField is one object deeper than usual.

Comment: for removing tree type just remove HierarchicalData and add your collection and for data can you provide a sample of your data

Comment: I have added a sample of my data.